# How to tie (enforced) a Debian package to a specific Ubuntu version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, deb, dpkg

### I have a C++ project built with `CMake` and packaged with `CPack` for Ubuntu,
I am issuing packages (`.deb`) for both `Ubuntu` `20.04` and `22.04` and I want to enforce that the correct version is installed on a corresponding machine.

##### Installing (local package):

```bash
$ sudo dpkg -i <my-package>.deb
```

##### Current solution:

I use the `preinst` script (which I pass to `CPack` via the `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA`) to check `lsb_release -sr` and compare against the `Ubuntu` version that the package was build for.

##### Limitation:

If the `preinst` script fails (e.g. when the machine and package versions do not match), the package is not installed (as expected), but the `postinst` script is still run.

---

**Is there a better way to do this version match enforcement?**
If not... how can I prevent `postinst` to run after `preinst` failed?

PS - I could check the version also in the `postinst` script and do nothing in that case, but I would leave that as a last resort.

Comment: You usually encode that in the .deb package, upload to the correctly labelled repository and `apt` downloads for the to correct distribution release from the correct repo.  In short you seem to have an 'X-Y' problem here that is typically not encoded with `cmake`.

Comment: Also, to be very plain: we do not generally install a Debian package on Ubuntu.  (There are exceptions for binary-all packages, think documentation or text only. But binaries should be built correctly. ) You can use launchpad.net to build and host your Ubuntu binaries.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel The packages are maintained and delivered outside of a `repo` / `hosting solution`, that's why I have the need to do this check on install.

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  You can create a repo with proper distro yourself. That would alleviate the problem at its source.  If you don;t want to do that you can possibly putz around and embed the release version in the version number; we sometimes do that just for clarity.

Comment: Otherrwise see the Debian developer manual and resources if you really think you must reinvent the apt logic inside of {pre,post}{inst,rm} scripts. You could touch a sentinel `/var/tmp/my_package_precondition_failed` in `preinst` and have `postinst` check and abort.  It's just scripting.  But I still believe you are tieing up the horse from the wrong end.  Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel I already have the Ubuntu version embedded in the package version (`CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_VERSION`) but that is as you said, just for clarity, it does not change my problem (someone can miss it and install the wrong thing).  
Regarding doing the extra check in `postinst` this is what I wanted to avoid in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I could add my own repo, but at least for now, that does not fit with my requirements, I need to manage these packages separately and deploy (controlled) specific versions to different people that will install them locally on different machines.

Comment: Why not defining the version of the dependent packages in control file (and you can uses trick about virtual packages and distribution packages to make different rules on Debian and Ubuntu. Note: if preinst fail, the system try to have consistend system, so running postinst for the old version (and ev. oldpostinst). Just check the version (and reason: upgrade, failed upgradem etc,) in your inst scripts. `preinst` is not the place to check dependencies.